# Statistics with discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working on a homework problem and I think that I am doing this correctly but i am not sure. This is the question:

An upper-level math class has 13 students: 4 of them are females. Two of the females
and four of the males live oﬀ campus. How many ways can a project group of three
students be chosen so that it has two on-campus members and at least one female?
Explain your answer

The answer that I came up with is 76. Not sure if that is right, at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I broke up the problem in 3 different stages to get to this answer.

Work:
I knew how many were male and female. And of those males and females knew how many were off campus and how many were on campus. What I did was 5nCr2 * 2nCr1 =10 then I found 5nCr1 * 2nCr1 * 6nCr1 = 60 and then I found 2nCr2 * 6nCr1 = 6 and added them together. First formula was to find 2 males on campus and choose 1 female on campus. Next formula was find the males on campus * females on campus * male and female off campus. Last formula was to find females off campus * male and female off campus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13 students composed of 9 males, 4 females.

4 females composed of 2 on campus, 2 off campus.

9 males composed of 5 on campus, 4 off campus.

13 students composes of 7 on campus, 6 off campus.

Let's find the amount of groups that have two on campus members.

You need to pick 2 of the 7, so $7\choose2$. Then you need one more from off campus, so $6\choose1$

So the number of groups with two on campus members is $$\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{1} = 126$$

Now you need at least one female. So let's find all of the groups of 2 on campus members and no females, then eliminate that from the above group.

You need to pick 2 on campus males. There are 5 to choose from, so $5\choose2$. Then you need one from off campus, so $4\choose1$, giving you
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1} = 40$$

$$126 - 40 = 86$$

Also a suggestion. You gave the answer you got but not how you got it. Having both would allow the person answering the question to know at what point you made an error and focus on that in the answer.

Comment: Howcome you never have to take into consideration the 13 students. I mean, howcome you don't have to use 13 to help solve the problem?

Comment: Also, is 86 the real answer? After finding the number of groups with 2 on campus members, you had mentioned that you need to find all of the groups of 2 on campus members and no females

Comment: If you were trying to find the probability of picking a group that meets the criteria from the entire population, then the size of 13 matters. But you're not looking for that, you just need the number of groups that satisfy your criteria. If you had 10 more students that lived on the campus border and had their own distinct "semi-on campus" classification, they couldn't possibly be in the groups you care about and hence wouldn't change the number of them. For any choice, you only care about picking from students that match the criteria. 13 is actually indirectly used, since $7+6=13$.

Comment: And assuming I haven't made an error, then yes, 86 is the real answer. 126 is all 2 on-campus, 1 off-campus groups. 40 is the number of those groups that have no female. So the remaining 86 must have at least one female.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I actually had misread what you had said after finding the number of groups with two on campus members. I didn't realize that the section where you are doing the work for the second part was a detailed working of that paragraph after finding the groups with 2 campus members. Thank you very much for your help